# How to write generic method

Tags: java, generics

I have many controllers. All of them extend AbstractController. Many of this controllers implement validate method.
How can I write generic validate method in AbstractController?

```
public class CarSearchCriteria extends AbstractController {
    ...

    public static final String VALIDATE = "/validate";
    private static final String TEMPLATE_PATH = "car/car_search";
    private static final String EMPTY_RESULT = " :: div-car-search";
    private static final String RESULT = " :: div-car-search-result";
    private static final String SEARCH_CRITERA = "carSearchCriteria";


    @RequestMapping(value = VALIDATE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validate(@Valid @ModelAttribute(SEARCH_CRITERA) CarSearchCriteria criteria, final BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return TEMPLATE_PATH + EMPTY_RESULT;
        }
        return TEMPLATE_PATH + RESULT;
    }

    ...
}

public abstract class AbstractController {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about actual "Generics" here or just using "generic" as a general keyword? Sounds more like polymorphism.

Comment: Why does a `CarSearchCriteria` have a (possible other) `CarSearchCriteria` as an argument for the `validate` method? What is its purpose?

Comment: @luk2302 i asked about actual "Generics", not about keyword.

Comment: I want to do method in AbstractContoller, because it's used in many Controllers which extend AbstractController.